# Get none null column row and other row when its null

Tags: sql

I have a problem and I wondered if I can do it only with sql.

So I have a table named: tbl, and columns a, b, c which a and b rows aren't null and c can be null, for example:

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | b1 | NULL |
| a2 | b2 | c2 |
| a3 | b3 | NULL |

And I wish to get the result with columns a and x when x is defined: take from b when c is null and take from c if its not null, so the output will be:

| a | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| a1 | b1 |
| a2 | c2 |
| a3 | b3 |

There is a sql command which can do the above?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `COALESCE` function, given that your DBMS supports it.

```
SELECT a, 
       COALESCE(c, b)
FROM tab
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
select a, nvl(c, b) from table;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your DBMS does not support the functions from answers above, you can do it with `CASE` function:

```
SELECT
  a,
  CASE
    WHEN c IS NULL THEN b
    ELSE c
    END AS col2
FROM
  tbl
```